# Jade string comparison failing

Tags: pug

I'm trying to use a string variable in an if statement like so

```
if data.Locality == "federal" 
    *other code*
```

However, the Locality string isn't matching as "federal". When I check the value in the data layer before it's touched by Jade, and when I put it in an element `p = data.Locality` it prints out as "federal" (minus the quotes). I've checked for whitespace and I can't find any. I've looked for possible built in comparison methods and I haven't found any. Any ideas on what might be happening or ways I could solve this?

Comment: Have you tried `- if (data.Locality == "federal") ` with a dash and parens?

Comment: @sean That caused the line to show up as plaintext

Comment: That's strange, the dash should signal unbuffered code: http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/

Comment: @sinclair In my searching, I haven't found any method comparable to .equals()

Comment: @sean Any idea why the comparison itself might be returning false?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that data.Locality was a pointer to a string rather than a string. It was automatically being dereferenced when I was examining it in the data layer and adding it to a another element in Jade, but not when I was doing the comparison. I ended up dereferencing it in my data layer by making a getter method that returned the string value, but you could probably dereference it in Jade as well.

Comment: I piped the reference to the `.toString()` method and it worked for me! Google lead me here and your answer helped me out a lot.